# GetObject works, CreateObject doesn't

Tags: excel, object, vbscript, createobject

Trying to write a script that

- If excel session already open, join it to this one,
- Excel session not open, thus create one.

First option works splendid! Second option doesn't work and does not give any explanation, just quits and does nothing!

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs
Dim XLWasRunning

XLWasRunning = True

Set objXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Not TypeName(objXLApp) = "Empty" Then
    strMessage = "Excel Running."
Else
    strMessage = "Excel Not Running."
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\GFD\Sam\Test\test.xlsx")
Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
```

EDIT : changed `CreateObject(, "Excel.Application")` to `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: `CreateObject(, "Excel.Application")` -> `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: Still nothing happens, also If I put a message box just after the `ELSE` I don't even get a message box.

Comment: If you want the instance to be visible you also need `objXLApp.Visible = True`.

Comment: I have changed it to `objXLApp.Visible = True` and it still doesn't work. Also when I run it with excel open, the cmd prompt stays open screen 4-5 seconds. When I don't have excel open, its on screen for a bout a tenth of a second?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Please [edit] your question and describe the problem in more detail. Is an Excel process created? Does the Window show? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, based on the comments you received, should work:

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs
Dim XLWasRunning
Dim strMessage

' Get running instance
Set objXLApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")

If Not objXLApp Is Nothing Then
    strMessage = "Excel Running."
    XLWasRunning = True
Else
    strMessage = "Excel Not Running."
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XLWasRunning = False
End If

objXLApp.Visible = True

Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
```

You might want to add the following to check if you should load the workbook again:

```
If Not XLWasRunning Then
    Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
    Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
End If
```

If Excel is already running you can also check if your Workbook is already loaded before loading it:

```
Dim bWorkbookFound
bWorkbookFound = False
For Each objXLWb In objXLApp.Workbooks
    If objXLWb.Name = "test.xlsx" Then
        ' Workbook already loaded
        bWorkbookFound = True
        objXLWb.Activate
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi, this is not correct, this is creating a new session without even checking current sessions.

Comment: If you mean that it opens up a new Excel window, that's because you are opening the Workbook again at the end of your code. You can check `XLWasRunning` and skip loading the Workbook.

Comment: In VBScript, I believe `Set objXLApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")` always creates a new instance. It is the same as `Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. To connect to an existing instance, use `Set objXLApp = GetObject( , "Excel.Application")`. Do **NOT** use `Set objXLApp = WScript.GetObject( , "Excel.Application")`, which will complain about the missing argument.